# Are header files necessary for Objective-C Unit Tests?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, tdd

Are header files necessary for Objective-C unit tests?

When using OCUnit, GHUnit, or GTM Unit Tests, I don't see the point of creating the header file for the unit test. It feels like it's just another file I need to keep updated if I decide to change my unit tests.

Tests are self-contained within a file and I don't reference one set of unit tests in another testing file.

Example: SetupTests.m (Using [GHUnit](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/index.html))

```
// SetupTests.m
@interface SetupTests : GHTestCase
{}
@end


@implementation SetupTests

- (void) testMath {
    GHAssertTrue((1+1)==3, @"Compiler isn't feeling well today :-(" );
}

- (void) testFirstUT {
    GHAssertEquals(1, 2, @"Should fail");
}
- (void) testSecondUT {
    GHAssertEquals(1, 1, @"Should pass");
}
@end
```

Comment: XCode 5.0 combines header and implementation files, when using the wizard to generate test classes.

Comment: Good to know. That probably doesn't apply to GHUnit or other 3rd party tests. It's best to just delete the .h for GHUnit in my previous testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not required. You are correct the header files primary function is to separate the interface from the implementation so that you can include the method declaration (and such) from other places.